# how to fix rewriting Rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have problem with my redirection rule in my website, i haven't this problem localy.

There is my project hierarchy:

```
1. my_website :
1.1 -->.htacess (1)
1.2 -->webroot
1.2.1 -> .htaccess (2)
1.2.2 -> index.php
```

htacces (1) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

htacces (2) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

When i enter link like : www.xxx.com/my_website,the redirection for my index.php work fine.

But if i enter link like www.xxx.com/my_website/folderName/action,i have an error (File not found).

thanks for your help.

Comment: We cannot somehow magically guess what is going on. We have absolutely no idea about your logic (you did not tell us) and we cannot do any debugging (it is _your_ systeme). So you will need to start debugging yourself. Enable rewrite logging on your system and check what is actually going on in your rewriting engine. Also check if that http 404 is raised by the http server itself or by your php based logic.

Comment: the http 404 is raised bu the server.

Comment: my logic is to redirect all url request to /webroot/index.php and $1 will be the url entred by client.

Comment: And what did the rewrite logging turn up? What do you see in your log files?

Comment: in OVH we can't use rewriteLog in .htaccess , https://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php/13477-RewriteLog-indisponible-sur-un-60GP.

Comment: That is a problem then, you cannot debug with a service like that. You will have to _guess_ then.